# Query in the database with row "trim"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Is there any way in PostgreSQL to ignore rows at the ends according to a rule, with good performance without using 2 subqueries?

For example, I want to get the values from the list by ignoring values less than 1 at the beginning of the list and at the end of the list:

```
ROWS:   0, 0.5, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.8, 1, 1.2, 1.3, 1, 0.9, 0, 0.2, 3, 2, 1, 0.9, 0.5, 0, 0.1, 0
SELECT: .......................[1, 1.2, 1.3, 1, 0.9, 0, 0.2, 3, 2, 1]....................
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can phrase this differently.  You want all rows between the first value at or greater than 1 and the last such value.

Assuming you have a unique id that orders the rows, you can do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(id) filter (where value >= 1) over () as minid1,
             max(id) filter (where value >= 1) over () as maxid1
      from t
     ) t
where id >= minid1 and id <= maxid1;
```

Comment: Perfect!
That's why I'm loving the migration from MySQL to PostgreSQL!